# Как сделать так, чтобы эта функция работала быстрее?

Tags: python

```
# a very ineffecient way to calculate a factorial 

from functools import lru_cache 

def partition(k, lmax=None):
    if lmax is None:
        lmax = k
    if k == 0:
        yield []
    for i in range(min(k, lmax), 0, -1):
        for p in partition(k - i, i):
            p.append(i)
            yield p
            
@lru_cache(maxsize=48000)                                          
def d(p):
    if not p:
        return 1
    p = list(p)
    if p[0] == 1:
        res = d(tuple(p[1:]))
    else:
        p[0] -= 1
        res = d(tuple(p))
        p[0] += 1
    for i in range(1, len(p)):
        if p[i - 1] < p[i]:
            p[i] -= 1
            res += d(tuple(p))
            p[i] += 1
    return res
    

def Q(n, r, s):
    if r > s:
        r, s = s, r 
    if (s - r) % n != 0:
        return 0
    qq = (s - r) // n
    sm = 0
    for p in partition(r):
        if len(p) <= n:
            pp = tuple(p)
            p2 = tuple(x + qq for x in p)
            sm += d(pp) * d(p2)
    return sm
    
print(Q(5,100,105))
```

с помощью CrazyElf сделать чтобы за 6 секунда руботала эта функция, теперь вот это обновленный код, что еще можно сделать чтобы эта функция работала быстрее?

```
from functools import lru_cache 
import math

@lru_cache(maxsize=48000000)                                                                         
def partitions(k, lmax=None, maxlen=None):
  return list(partition(k,lmax,maxlen))

def partition(k, lmax=None, maxlen=None):
    if lmax is None:
        lmax = k
    if maxlen is None:
        maxlen = k
    if maxlen < 0:
      return
    if k == 0:
        yield []
    for i in range(min(k, lmax), 0, -1):
        for p in partitions(k - i, i, maxlen - 1):
            yield [i] + p
            
@lru_cache(maxsize=48000000)     
def d(p):
  s = math.factorial(sum(p))
  n = len(p)
  for i, ei in enumerate(p):
    for j, ej in enumerate(p[i + 1:]):
      s *= ei - ej + j + 1
  for i, ei in enumerate(p):
      s //= math.factorial(ei + n - 1 - i)
  return s
  
def Q(n, r, s):
    if r > s:
        r, s = s, r 
    if (s - r) % n != 0:
        return 0
    qq = (s - r) // n
    sm = 0
    if qq == 0:
      for p in partition(r, maxlen=n):
        pp = tuple(p) 
        sm += d(pp)**2
    else:
      for p in partition(r, maxlen=n):
        pp = tuple(p) 
        p2 = tuple([x + qq for x in p + [0]*(n - len(p))])
        sm += d(pp) * d(p2)
    return sm
    
print(Q(5,100,105))
```

Comment: Сложно оптимизировать код, о котором неизвестно, что он должен делать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поставьте перед каждой вашей функцией такой же декоратор, который уже имеется на одной из функций:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=48000)
def ...
```

И тогда код отработает моментально. Результат:

```
3533343320884635898708258511468514257188006702535057407220
```

А в целом не очень понятно, что делают эти функции и что вы вообще хотите от этого кода.

Ну то есть по комментарию в начале кода я понимаю, что это имеет отношение к факториалам и для вычисления факториалов есть какие-то быстрые и простые способы. Но тем не менее, что происходит в вашем коде, сходу понять сложно.

**Update:** Для изменённого кода рецепт примерно такой же. Вынесите вызов функции `math.factorial` в отдельную функцию, которую оберните в кэширующий декоратор:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=2**20)
def factorial(n):
    return math.factorial(n)
 
def d(p):
  s = factorial(sum(p)) # <- здесь изменение
  n = len(p)
  for i, ei in enumerate(p):
    for j, ej in enumerate(p[i + 1:]):
      s *= ei - ej + j + 1
  for i, ei in enumerate(p):
      s //= factorial(ei + n - 1 - i) # <- здесь изменение
  return s
```

Определить, какой реальный размер кэша нужен в вашем конкретно случае, вы можете посмотрев статистику использования кэширующего декоратора для функции:

```
print(partitions.cache_info())
print(factorial.cache_info())
```

У меня получилось:

```
CacheInfo(hits=51710, misses=7245, maxsize=48000000, currsize=7245)
CacheInfo(hits=546066, misses=105, maxsize=1048576, currsize=105)
```

Соответственно, для функции `partitions` было бы достаточно кэша размером 7245 элементов, а для `factorial` 105 элементов.

В Google Colab ваш код выполнился за 4.77 µs (микросекунды) с результатом:

```
95493674950242831791026293548399314748158581690891972235749696738751990663887812808657625870889440121523405901442355409994205
```

Comment: спасибо благодоря вам могли сократить до 6 секунда, теперь вот этот так обновили код, что еще можно сделать чтобы эта функция работала быстрее? то есть обновил там код

Comment: @SayatOtarbay Я обновил ответ